# Печатная форма в c#. Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, form, print

Есть задача создания печатного документа из приложения на c# в vs2015. Документ нужен очень четких размеров и расположения элементов в форме. Вроде как для этих целей служат Crystal Reports И Winforms. Может есть какие-то способы попроще? Задача создать документ потом его через виртуальный принтер выводить в pdf и отправлять по электронке. Полей в документе достаточно много и заполнятся они будут результатами запроса из бд.

Comment: Чёткость размеров и расположения обеспечивается правильным программированием.  Я бы посоветовал WPF, но у него сложный порог вхождения. Так что используйте то, что знаете сами.

Comment: А сразу генерировать PDF, без виртуального принтера не вариант? PDFSharp + MigraDoc, хоть в консоли генерируйте и отправляйте на реальный принтер. Есть и другие либы для этого, но мне хватает этих за глаза на текущих задачах.

Comment: Спасибо, хороший вариант.  Существует ли какой-то wisywig designer  или ручками все описываем элементы документа. У меня документ куча текстовых блоков. Приблизительный вид документа http://www.logists.by/uploads/images/54f19248852c2830432fe7c19e5a0024.png